# Ruby version not in ruby-build list for rbenv

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I'm using Rails 4.2 and wanted to update my Ruby version as well with rbenv.

I used Homebrew to install ruby-build and no matter how many times I try to update via `brew`, Ruby version 2.1.3 won't show when I run `rbenv install --list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you installed rbenv and ruby-build with homebrew and when you do `echo $(rbenv root)`, you get `/usr/local/var/rbenv` instead of `/Users/<username>/.rbenv`, here is how to fix the issue.

---

When you install rbenv with homebrew, homebrew says:

```
To use Homebrew's directories rather than ~/.rbenv add to your profile:
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
```

Don't do that. Remove that line from your profile. Make sure you refresh your terminal after.

Then remove any signs of rbenv in the /usr/local/var directory:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/var/rbenv
```

Now when I do `echo $(rbenv root)` I get `/Users/<username>/.rbenv` instead of `/usr/local/var/rbenv`.

That fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

Usually, follow these steps to install a new Ruby version with `rbenv`:

```
$ brew update               
$ brew upgrade ruby-build
$ brew upgrade rbenv
```

Check which versions are available after updating:

```
$ ruby-build --definitions
```

Install a specific version (for example `2.1.3`) with:

```
$ rbenv install 2.1.3
```

Or if you are interested into improved support for UTF8 characters in the `irb` console:

```
$ RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-readline-dir=`brew --prefix readline` rbenv install 2.1.3
```

After these steps I usually set the newest version as my global default:

```
$ rbenv global 2.1.3
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I really appreciate the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended installation from (https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) states that you should install ruby-build as an rbenv plug-in.

- I uninstalled ruby-build via Homebrew (`brew uninstall ruby-build`)
- Navigated to ruby-build on my local machine and deleted it
- `git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build`

Now, when I run `rbenv install --list`, I see Ruby 2.1.3. A quick installation of: `rbenv install 2.1.3` and I am now free to use 2.1.3 where I like. This also worked for my teammate.

Comment: Don't forget to periodically pull new changes in by running `git pull` in ~/.rbenv and ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build or the problem will repeat itself.

Answer (score 0):

Please update by `brew upgrade ruby-build` and then you should see `2.1.3` in `rbenv install --list`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update ruby build. After update you can install all current suported versions.

If you using rbenv installed via git use

`cd "$(rbenv root)"/plugins/ruby-build && git pull`

Or via home brew

```
$ brew upgrade ruby-build
$ brew upgrade rbenv
```