# Is it possible to install ruby 2.3.4 on Mac Os 10.7.5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rbenv

I would like to upgrade to Rails 5.1

I am using an old mac computer with OS 10.7.5 and, on my understanding, I can not upgrade the operating system to a newer version. If there is a way, please let me know. I am developing on this computer using Rails 4.2.6. I want to upgrade to Rails 5.1 but, it will need Ruby >= 2.2.2. My ruby 2.1.1 is the better I can get, according to `rbenv install --list`. I tried reinstalling rbenv and ruby-build and upgrading them but, the `rbenv install --list` doesn't upgrade to the newest versions of ruby.

To give you heads up, `.rbenv/plugins` does not exist in my computer.

I read and tried all the suggestions I found on stackoverflow.com and google similar to my case but, none of them worked for me.

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: How about upgrading Mac OS X ?

Comment: "on my understanding, I can not upgrade the operating system to a newer version. If there is a way, please let me know." - Why not? Your boss doesn't let you, your disk is full, you are banned from App Store, what?

Comment: Update rbenv ([`brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26434459/2483313)) and try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your mac can use 10.7.5 you can upgrade your mac to version 10.11 (I'm using it so I can answer it) my opinion your for your ruby version is deal with homebrew you can upgrade your homebrew and then from homebrew you upgrade rbenv and so on.

Below is some step by step to install rails with RBENV, probably you can follow along, what command that probably you missed

1. ### rbenv versions

   - check your rbenv version
   - if you think you need to upgrade you can use command below
   - **brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build**
2. ### rbenv install -l

   - check list of ruby that can be installed with rbenv
3. ### rbenv install 2.3.1

   - this is sample to install ruby version 2.3.1
   - ruby will be copied to /Users/%your_user_name%/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1
   - this is just sample version, use the latest / stable from command number 2
4. ### rbenv global 2.3.1

   - set global ruby to version 2.3.1
5. ### rbenv local 2.1.1

   - after you set global (with version 2.3.1) in case you want specific folder with version 2.1.1 you can set local folder with this command, so the new ruby Don't messed up your old project
6. ### rbenv rehash

   - this command will apply new ruby version that you just install

Comment: Thank you very much for your time widjajayd. Unfortunately, on the step #2, I received the following message: $ brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build
Error: rbenv 1.1.1 already installed
Error: ruby-build 20170523 already installed

Comment: use brew upgrade rbenv --HEAD  link source: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/656

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable time helping me. I received some errors. I took care of some of them. Some I couldn't. For example:                                                                                            promt$ brew upgrade rbenv --HEAD
Error: rbenv HEAD-615f844 already installed